# I have a Logitech G600 mouse that is listed twice on xinput list (as in same name and properties). How do I update this .conf to reflect that?

Tags: xorg, mouse, xinput

This is the script:

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "My Mouse"
MatchIsPointer "yes"
Option "AccelerationProfile" "-1"
Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
Option "AccelSpeed" "-1"
EndSection
```

It's used to disable mouse acceleration and is taken from [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_acceleration#Disabling_mouse_acceleration) page.

The script doesn't work, and I am assuming it is something to do with the fact that it only affects one of the G600s listed. How do I fix it?

Comment: Your supposition is wrong, `MatchIsPointer "yes"` means this section will apply to all mice.